# Pasar valores entre Activity AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android-studio

quiero pasar dos valores de una Activity a otra, este es mi código

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


EditText ip_intro;

Button botonPlantaBaja;
Button botonPlanta0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    botonPlantaBaja = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_pb);
    botonPlantaBaja.setOnClickListener(this);

    botonPlanta0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_p0);
    botonPlanta0.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.boton_pb:
            String datobaja= ip_intro.getText().toString();
            int p_baja=-1;
            Intent intent_baja = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            intent_baja.putExtra("DATO",datobaja);
            intent_baja.putExtra("PLANTA",p_baja);
            startActivity(intent_baja);
            break;
        case R.id.boton_p0:
            String dato0= ip_intro.getText().toString();
            int p_0=0;
            Intent intent_0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            intent_0.putExtra("DATO",dato0);
            intent_0.putExtra("PLANTA",p_0);
            startActivity(intent_0);
            break;
```

Y de la clase donde quiero pasar los valores

SecondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
SensorEventListener {

private TextView texto_ip;
private TextView texto_planta;
private String dato_ip;
int num_planta;


    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    texto_ip= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto_ip);
    texto_planta= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto_planta);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle datos= intent.getExtras();

    dato_ip= datos.getString("DATO");
    texto_ip.setText(dato_ip);
    num_planta=datos.getInt("PLANTA");
    texto_planta.setText("Estamos en la planta: "+num_planta);
}
```

¿Alguien me podría ayudar, y decirme dónde está el fallo? Y si me pudiese poner un código se lo agradecería mucho

Saludos

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error exactamente? Yo lo veo correcto

Comment: Este es el típico error que se soluciona poniendo un par de Breakpoints (en el onclick y en el oncreate de la segunda actividad) y debugeando cada variable que usas para comprobar que no haya ningun valor incorrecto... pero bueno

Comment: @Héctor el problema ocurre cuando ejecuto la aplicación y pulso uno de los botones, en la que automáticamente se cierra la aplicación.

Comment: @Corpex no se muy bien utilizar los breakpoints, pero no me queda otra, voy a ver

Comment: Va ya se que te falta, te pongo respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se te ha olvidado el `findViewById` de `ip_intro` en el onCreate de la MainActivity.

```
EditText ip_intro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.aquiPonTuVista);
```

Sin esto cuando haces `String datobaja= ip_intro.getText().toString();` te va a fallar porque no tienes vinculada la vista del edittext a la variable.

Comment: Ostias vaya fallo jaja Era eso, muchas gracias :)